# How to fix typescript error (Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to fix typescript error?

I cloned the application from the working git repository, launched and received the error:

> Property 'language' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{
>   children?: ReactNode; }>'.  TS2339

```
    <div className="login-block__form__head__text">
      {// @ts-ignore
      this.props.language === 'EN'// err
        ? 'Login'
        : 'LOGIN'}{' '}
    </div>
```

Unfortunately, I do not know the typescript, so I have to ask for help.

[image]

Comment: What repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case, you didn't define props types.

```
interface PropType {
  language: string,
}

export default class ComponentName extends React.Component<PropType> {
...
}
```

if you want to learn more about typescript, the following links would be helpful.

- [typescript in 5min](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html)